# AWS Amplify Auth with Cognito User Pool not returning nonce or at_hash claim in JWT id_token

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-amplify

I'm trying to use Amplify Auth to implement an OpenID Connect Implicit Flow to provide SSO to a number of React clients.

I've been able to get this working with Cognito Hosted UI, but that requires other apps users to click a button to confirm login in order to authenticate. I'd prefer for it to be seamless *ie* when a user is logged in on one site and navigate to another they are automatically authenticated if they have a session with the auth provider.

To try and achieve this I've set up a separate Amplify app that uses the React Authenticator Component.

I'm able to authenticate with this and redirect back to the client. However the `id_token` doesn't contain the `at_hash` or `nonce` claim. Presumably, the `at_hash` is missing because the authentication provider app is not sending the `responseType` of `token id_token` when it authenticates with Cognito. The `nonce` is missing because I haven't found a way to pass it in.

1. Is there a way to get Amplify Authenticator SignIn to request an `id_token` with the `at_hash` claim?
2. Is it possible to pass a `nonce` value through to the `id_token` claims?

*Note*
I'm trying to adhere to: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowSteps
Specifically for this part: *3.2.2.10.  ID Token*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Authenticator, ConfirmSignIn, SignIn } from 'aws-amplify-react';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const getSearchParams = () =>
    window.location.search.substr(1);

const getValueFromSearchParam = (key) =>
    new URLSearchParams(getSearchParams()).get(key);

const getRedirectUri = () => {
    const redirect_uri = getValueFromSearchParam('redirect_uri');
    return redirect_uri ? decodeURI(redirect_uri) : null;
};

const Login = () => {
    const handleAuthStateChange = (state) => {
        if(state === 'signedIn') {
            const redirect_uri = getRedirectUri();
            const state = getValueFromSearchParam('state');
            if(redirect_uri === null) {
                throw new Error('No redirect_uri provided');
            }
            Auth.currentSession().then(currentSession => {
                const id_token = currentSession.idToken.jwtToken;
                const access_token = currentSession.accessToken.jwtToken;
                const redirect = `${redirect_uri}#access_token=${access_token}&id_token=${id_token}&state=${state}`;
                window.location.replace(redirect);
            }).catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
    };

    return (
        <Authenticator
            hideDefault={true}
            onStateChange={handleAuthStateChange}
        >
            <SignIn  />
            <ConfirmSignIn/>
        </Authenticator>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few issues here that may be of interest:

- Cognito lacks some standards based support, as you are noticing
- If you use response_type = token id_token you will be limited to fixed 60 minute user sessions
- Amplify may not be the most standard based library in terms of nonce parameters etc
- Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) is recommended these days for SPAs - you may find this an easier way to implement the post login checks you are looking for

Unfortunately you may need to make some trade offs when working with Cognito - and make the 'least bad choice'. If it helps, here is some stuff of mine to compare against:

- [Cognito integration using OIDC Client Library](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts)
- [Online Link to Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/)
- [Cognito Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/08/how-to-run-the-react-js-spa/)
- [SPA Token Renewal Notes](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/)

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been slowly coming to a similar conclusion, it's been difficult to totally rule anything out, as I generally put it down to me having missed something. So it's really helpful to hear this. 

I'll have a read through those links tomorrow morning.

Comment: Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) looks promising thanks for that too.

Comment: Auth code flow with custom UI is not supported in cognito